# Parameterizing and editing a model using ThreeJS or X3DOM in the browser

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl, x3dom

I am using ThreeJs to render some STL files in the browser. 
I am trying to figure out if I can add parameters to these models, so that I can edit these models using ThreeJs or X3DOM. 
For example I have a cube and I want to add a text parameter to this cube.
When the text parameter is passed to ThreeJS, it embosses the text on the cube at a specific location.

I don't mind converting the STL files to the ThreeJS model Js file or X3D files as long as I can parameterize the rendering to add text to the basic structure.

I want to know if anyone has had experience doing this kind of 3D parameterization.

1. Is this possible in ThreeJS or X3DOM?
2. If yes, then is there any documentation that I could use to achieve this?

If these libraries cannot handle this case, then are there any other libraries which can achieve the same?

Edit
My question is more about how I can add parameters to the model itself. Can we have parameters in ThreeJS models themselves, which ThreeJS understands out of the box. Let me ignore the text example, if I consider a simple cube in a model file, is there a way to make Threejs understand its side length as param from the model, and any changes to this param automatically gets reflected into the visualization. I.e. IF I change the side length from 1 to 3, Threejs renders a larger cube.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it answers your question, but personally I would create a subclass of an empty 3D object, and apply your effects programmatically, after the base model is loaded.

Here's how I do with three.js (ideally, this is in a separated file) :

```
var EmbossedCube = function( text, onLoaded ) {
  THREE.Object3D.apply(this);

  var self = this;
  var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();

  loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0xff5533 } );

    // apply effects on the material, or the geometry
    // according to `text`

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( event.content, material );

    // transform the mesh locally if needed

    self.add( mesh );
    onLoaded && onLoaded( self );
  } );

  loader.load( './model.stl' );
};
EmbossedCube.prototype = Object.create( THREE.Object3D.prototype );

// methods of EmbossedCube

EmbossedCube.prototype.constructor = THREE.Object3D;
```

Then you can create such an object, and add it to your scene:

```
var cube = new EmbossedCube("beep", function(obj){
  // you can translate/rotate the object if needed
  scene.add( obj );
});
```

It could be not the simplest way to do it, but I think it offers a good reusability on the long term.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vincent. However my question is more about how I can add parameters to the model itself. Can we have parameters in ThreeJS models themselves, which ThreeJS understands out of the box. Let me ignore the text example, if I consider a simple cube in a model file, is there a way to make Threejs understand its side length as param from the model, and any changes to this param automatically gets reflected into the visualization. I.e. IF I change the side length from 1 to 3, Threejs renders a larger cube.

Comment: I'm think you try to mix _format_ and _process_ :-| If what you want is an url that can output customized things, I think you need a server-side process which modify a base model according to arguments. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping to push this to the client side using Threejs. :) I am hoping to do something like http://joostn.github.io/OpenJsCad/ OpenJsCad is great, but I like the rendering performance of ThreeJs and X3Dom better. Hence this question wrt the two popular frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Explore the [va3c viewer](http://va3c.github.io/), which has options for opening files from REVIT, grasshopper etc.

You might try opening your files first in Rhino + GH, then creating those parameters that you need and then importing it using va3c.

This is a hunch and I cannot try until you give an actual file with details about the usecase.

Tell me if this works. ;)